# Beautifulsoup4 does not properly grab div (as opposed to BS3)

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have both BeautifulSoup 3x and 4x installed:

```
$ pip2 search beautifulsoup
beautifulscraper (1.1.0)                          - Python web-scraping library that wraps urllib2 and BeautifulSoup.
scrapy-beautifulsoup (0.0.2)                      - Simple Scrapy middleware to process non-well-formed HTML with BeautifulSoup
ipython-beautifulsoup (0.3)                       - Custom rendering of beautifulsoup objects       in IPython notebook and qtconsole
django-beautifulsoup-test (1.1.3)                 - TestCase class for using BeautifulSoup with Django tests
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)                             - HTML/XML parser for quick-turnaround applications like screen-scraping.
  INSTALLED: 3.2.1 (latest)
beautifulsoup4-slurp (0.0.2)                      - Slurp packages Beautifulsoup4 into command line.
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)                            - Screen-scraping library
  INSTALLED: 4.6.0 (latest)
beautifulsoupselect (0.2)                         - Simple wrapper to integrate BeautifulSoup and soupselect.py in a single package
```

I have the following HTML-Code (cut short for better visuals) in a text file:

```
<div class="postarea">
<div align="center"><img src="http://images" width="500" height="120" /></div>
<p><info></info><br />
<strong>Season of Monsters</p>
<p>Conflict in wartime.</p>
<p><span id="more-473091"></span></p>
<hr /><strong>Test44</strong></p>
<p><singlelink></singlelink><br />
<strong><span style="color:#8E2323;">Test1| Test2| Test3</span></strong></p>
<p><a href="http://gregregrgreg" rel="nofollow">testesttest</a></p>
</div>
</html>
```

I use the following python code with BeautifulSoup4:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('html.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
postarea=soup.find('div', class_ = "postarea")
print postarea
```

I'm expecting everything from that text file except the closing html-tag. What I'm getting instead is this:

```
<div class="postarea">
<div align="center"><img height="120" src="http://images" width="500"/></div>
<p><info></info><br/>
<strong>Season of Monsters</strong></p>
<p>Conflict in wartime.</p>
<p><span id="more-473091"></span></p>
<hr/><strong>Test44</strong></div>
```

It added a closing strong-tag to the 4th line and just closed the initial div after `<strong>Test44</strong>`

If I use this code instead with BeautifulSoup3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
with open('html.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
postarea=soup.find('div', {"class" : "postarea"})
print postarea
```

I get the desired result (even though it also adds a closing strong-tag in line 4).

How does BS actually grab a div then? Because if it just looks for the matching closing-div-tag I should get a different result.

How can I grab it properly?

Thanks in advance,

Hachel

Comment: Try using `BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")` instead. You might need to install `lxml`.

Comment: This HTML is horribly malformed. Specifically, the first `strong` isn't closed properly and there's a stray `</p>` somewhere, which the parser "corrects" to a `</div>`, thus giving you the result you see. Try different parsers (like `BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')`) and see which one works best for you.